# boost::shared_polymorphic_downcast is gone in boost 1.53.0. What should I use instead?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

`boost::shared_polymorphic_downcast` disappeared between boost [1.52.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp) and [1.53.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp).  Nothing is mentioned about this in the [release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_53_0.html), and the commit (r81463) contains only the cryptic log message "Update shared_ptr casts."

It is not clear to me what I should be using now instead, or why this functionality was removed.  Can anybody help?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the insightful comments.  I find myself a bit frustrated that boost will make backwards-incompatible changes in a release without any justification or notice, and I also find it frustrating that they remove useful features.  But based on the responses, I can do what I want in two lines of code instead of one, so I think that will suffice.  Still, I am leaving this question "unanswered" because nobody has provided a simple way to get the old behavior of `boost::shared_polymorphic_downcast`; that is, to use a `dynamic_cast` when debugging is enabled and a `static_cast` when it is not.

Comment: Doesn't `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast` fit your needs?

Comment: `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast` will perform the dynamic_cast just fine, but `boost::shared_polymorphic_downcast` has the added benefit of asserting that the dynamic cast actually _succeeds_.

Comment: @JimGarrison: So does `dynamic_pointer_cast`; if it fails, it returns a null `shared_ptr`. Just like `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @NicolBolas returning a null `shared_ptr` is not the same as having an assert that fails.

Comment: why use boost when c++ dynamic_cast() does the same (with less dependancies)

Comment: @JimGarrison: Asserts only fail in debug. This way forces you to always test the result.

Comment: @NicolBolas polymorphic casts are designed precisely for the case when I expect it to always succeed.  Thus, testing the result in non-debug settings is wasteful.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm for justification.

Comment: I use the benefit of a boost::polymorphic_down_cast, on code vetted by our rigorous QA process, to gain the benefit of assertion tested dynamic_casts in debug code (with likely slower RTTI), and a speedy re-interpret_cast in release builds. For us it's in our game graphics engine.

Answer (score 10):

Use `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast`.

The update it talks about is to match the design of C++11. In C++11 the pointer casts are generalized as the functions `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` (and friends) to allow us to write:

```
template <typename PointerToBase> // models Base* in some way
void foo(PointerToBase ptr)
{
    auto ptrToDerived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(ptr);
}
```

So that `PointerToBase` could be a raw `Base*` or a `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, without us writing cases.

Boost of course simply wants to match C++ as much as possible.